# How to get list of today meetings from EWS using ews-javascript-api?

Tags: node.js, exchangewebservices, ews-javascript-api

I have email/password of MS Exchange account.

Also, I have the timeframe (today).

So how can I get the list of all meetings that MS EXchange account for today?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the author of ews-javascript-api had an example here:

https://gist.github.com/gautamsi/ba0561da1b4a2b29478943ba5f002328

```
import { ExchangeService, ExchangeVersion, WebCredentials, Uri, DateTime, CalendarView, WellKnownFolderName, EwsLogging } from "ews-javascript-api";
import credentials = require("./credentials"); //for username and password
EwsLogging.DebugLogEnabled = false;

var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(credentials.userName, credentials.password);
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/Ews/Exchange.asmx");

var view = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now.Add(-1, "week"), DateTime.Now); // appointments in last one week.
service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, view).then((response) => {
    let appointments = response.Items;
    let appointment = appointments[0];
    console.log("Subject: " + appointment.Subject);
    console.log("Start Time: " + appointment.Start);
    console.log("End Time: " + appointment.End);
    console.log("Recipients: ");
    appointment.RequiredAttendees.Items.forEach((a) => {
        console.log(a.Address);
    });
    console.log("unique id: " + appointment.Id.UniqueId, true, true);

}, function (error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```